Failed review audit: high score question, but no code
I failed this review audit*, but I don't understand that. The question is asking about an error, but does not include any code.
I think at least it should include some environment info such as OS, the version of Python and the module. There is no way to start debugging without those.

*Note that the question has been edited in response to this Meta question. The version that existed before, and that this Meta question was asked about, was https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78279136/2.

Is code needed when any ML script using Gensim will throw that error?

On one hand I agree with Rene that the question doesn't need code when all scripts cause the error. On the other hand, it's not clear from the question alone that this is the case. Sure, if you know the cause, then it is clear, but from the question alone, I would have also asked for code or at least the exact compiler command that was called.

I personally hate review audits.  It seems like the system could judge your reviews by how well you agree with other reviewers on actual items to be reviewed rather than throwing in tricky edge cases and tests.

@StephenOstermiller That would have its own problems; enforcing conformity in subjective cases is probably not a good thing, and enforcing conformity in cases where reviewers tend to get results outright wrong (e.g. failing to notice plagiarism) is even worse. Using only review tasks where the correct action is totally unambiguous and there's no room for reasonable debate avoids those problems - in theory, you can't get punished for other reviewers' incompetence or for tending to have different opinions on truly subjective cases. Trouble is, not all the audits really are so unambiguous...

My main objection here is that the question is presented as though the OP is simply trying to run someone else's program, and has no intention of actually programming. On the other hand, it's self-answered and describes a fairly common version-incompatibility issue (or at least one that was common at the time).

I also lost my audit privilege twice on stuff like this. Sometimes its really not clear for me on first glance, why certain questions have a high voting on them. Often very old questions that seem very open to me have a high voting, maybe because the answers were useful to a lot of people even if the question wasnt very high quality.

The problem the question asker was experiencing was that every time they import Gensim from a Python script, they see the quoted import error, and this has happened because they are using the latest version of SciPy which is (for now) incompatible with Gensim, because Gensim tries to import something from SciPy that SciPy has removed in the latest version. There's no script shown in the question because literally just an import is enough. The question isn't asking us to debug the asker's code; instead it's asking us to tell them what's wrong in their environment that's preventing the library from working properly.
Admittedly, the question (in the form that you saw it) didn't do a great job of spelling this out. It would've been better if it had spelt out that just importing Gensim was enough to trigger the error and exhibited the import statement that causes the error, so that a reader unfamiliar with the error message would understand the question. Such readers are part of the audience of the question and it's worth making the question clear to them.
Nonetheless, evidently the question was clear to its primary audience - namely people experiencing the same problem as the asker. Someone who encountered that error message, googled it, and found that question, would have no problem at all inferring the missing details - because they've just experienced them themselves. Such readers are presumably responsible for the 29 upvotes the question has.
What's the appropriate thing to do with such a question? Not to close it, I would think - certainly not at this point. The question was unclear to a reader unfamiliar with the problem prior to the answers being posted, but the answers have clarified it. There was only one useful thing left to do, I think, which is to edit the question to make clear that just importing Gensim is enough to trigger the error. I just installed Gensim locally, reproduced the error, and made precisely such an edit; problem solved.
That leaves the question of whether your audit failure was fair. No, it clearly wasn't. It would've been harsh to fail an audit even if you had tried to close this question (given that without the answers it is kind of unclear), but you didn't even do that; all you tried to do was leave a comment via the "Share feedback" option, which is an action that can potentially make perfect sense on both good questions and bad ones. It's illogical for that action to ever cause an audit failure; that it does so specifically on questions that the system believes to be good questions is even worse, because the instructions for the queue explicitly state that you should:

Edit or share feedback on questions that are good, but could use some help.

and yet doing this will fail audits. Note also the contradiction between this policy documented in the site help text and what mods have written on Meta - namely that:

"Share feedback" is shorthand for "Share feedback that this post should be closed."

which seems to be corroborated by the canned comments in the "Share feedback" section of the wizard mapping to question close reasons. I can only assume that Stephen is correct that the intent behind the tool is (for some reason that I cannot fathom) that you will only use "Share feedback" for questions that deserve to be downvoted, closed and deleted, and that we are supposed to intuitively understand that the phrase "questions that are good, but could use some help" is actually politically correct code for "worthless garbage". Obviously, it's deeply unhelpful that we're expected to read between the lines like this and that you get punished if you take the instructions at face value.
It seems to me that audits in this queue are just fundamentally illogical and broken, I'm afraid. This isn't the case in all queues - for instance, if you fail an audit in the Suggested Edit queue, you definitely deserved to fail. But in this queue it seems the audits are dumb and you will sometimes arbitrarily fail audits for taking totally appropriate actions, and the only way to avoid it is to either not use the queue or to game the audits by opening each question in a separate tab to check if the score matches (and thus sniff out the audits). Yeah, this is broken. Only way it's going to change is if the staff fix the audit system, though, so you'll just have to deal with the broken state of affairs as you see fit. Sorry.

in my experience it were only "known good" audits that are flawed (or shouls I say just broken). "Known bad" ones - those expecting negative feedback - seem to be in much better shape. This is not surprising if you compare "signal quality" for these two kinds of audits. "Known good" ones can be triggered by just a handful upvotes from inexperienced 15-rep users (some of which may be voting up solely while hunting for voting badges). This isn't even close to "known bad" audits made from votes down of 125-rep users and flags that are quite thoroughly vetted before marked helpful

"Share feedback" ... is an action that can potentially make perfect sense on both good questions and bad ones. It's illogical for that action to ever cause an audit failure. <- While I agree in principle, I'm not sure how it could be implemented in practice unless we just remove "Share feedback" as an option entirely. Otherwise robo-reviewers would definitely abuse this loophole to "Share feedback" on every review.

@tdy such a loophole already exists - the "Edit" option always passes audits.

@MarkAmery Oof... then maybe I'm overestimating the robo-review risk. But in fairness, edits bump posts while comments do not, so it's much harder to spam 80+ useless edits per day (without being caught) than 80+ useless comments.
